# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5LinguistTools" despite having qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools installed

Tags: dependencies, compiling, qt5

I am trying to compile something, get this error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5LinguistTools"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5LinguistToolsConfig.cmake
    qt5linguisttools-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5LinguistTools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "Qt5LinguistTools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "Qt5LinguistTools" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I have qttools5-dev and qttools5-dev-tools installed.

```
baconcatbug@BCB:~$ sudo apt install qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qttools5-dev is already the newest version (5.12.8-0ubuntu1).
qttools5-dev-tools is already the newest version (5.12.8-0ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

and my env flags have CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH set

````
baconcatbug@BCB:~$ printenv | grep CMAKE
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5LinguistTools```
 any ideas why it's not working?
````

Comment: Same problem here...